# Allocating an object of abstract class type when trying to create a SceneNode

Tags: c++, object, c++11, abstract, sfml

I have an issue I don't manage to solve in C++.

I have a class called SceneNode. In this class, there isn't any virtual function and in the private members, I have a vector of unique_ptr and a raw pointer to a SceneNode object.
When try to allocate a new SceneNode, I get the following error: allocating an object of abstract class type "SceneNode".

Here's the code:

```
    class SceneNode : public  sf::Drawable,
                  public  sf::Transformable,
                  private sf::NonCopyable
{

    //OVERVIEW: A SceneNode is a node from the scene graph. It represents a graphical element
    //A typical SceneNode is (PARENT, CHILDREN, TRANSFORM)
    //With TRANSFORM containing several information:
    //TRANSFORM.POS = the position of this
    //TRANSFORM.ROTATION = the rotation of this

    //The transformation of this is always relative to its parent
    //Therefore, TRANSFORM.POS is the position of this, relatively to its parent


    //NB: - a SceneNode is not copyable !
    //    - It's an abstract class

public:

    //--------------------------------------------
    //Typedefs
    //--------------------------------------------
    typedef std::unique_ptr<SceneNode> UniquePtr;
    typedef sf::Vector2f               Position;

public:

    //--------------------------------------------
    //Constructors
    //--------------------------------------------
    SceneNode();
        //REQUIRES: /
        //MODIFIES: this
        //EFFECTS: initializes this with this_post.PARENT = no parent
        //         and this.CHILDREN = { ⦰ }

public:

    //--------------------------------------------
    //Public member functions
    //--------------------------------------------
    void attachChild(UniquePtr child);
        //REQUIRES: child != nullptr
        //MODIFIES: this
        //EFFECTS: if child == nullptr, stops the program;
        //         else, this_post.CHILDREN = this.CHILDREN U { child }

    UniquePtr detachChild(const SceneNode& child);
        //REQUIRES: /
        //MODIFIES: this
        //EFFECTS: if child in this.CHILDREN, this_post.CHILDREN = this.CHILDREN \ child && returns a unique_ptr to the child, don't catch it to let it being freed

    sf::Transform getWorldTransform() const;
        //REQUIRES: /
        //MODIFIES: /
        //EFFECTS: returns the absolute transformation of this

    Position getWorldPosition() const;
        //REQUIRES: /
        //MODIFIES: /
        //EFFECTS: returns the absolute position of this



private:

    //--------------------------------------------
    //Representation
    //--------------------------------------------
    SceneNode*             mParent;
    std::vector<UniquePtr> mChildren;



};`
```

What can I do ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do any of `sf::Drawable`, `sf::Transformable` or `sf::NonCopyable` have pure virtual functions that you didn't override?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes, yes they do: http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Drawable.php

Comment: @clcto Yep - all are SFML classes, and Drawable needs a Draw()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are inheriting from abstract interfaces like [sf::Drawable](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Drawable.php) but not implementing the pure virtual functions they define (the draw() function in the case of Drawable). If you implement those functions in your class you should get rid of the compiler errors.